# Colab FileNotFoundError - Stable Diffusion Unfiltered

Tags: google-colaboratory, filenotfounderror, stable-diffusion

so I'm a complete nawb to this. I googled the problem but found only a bunch of unrelated entries.

I'm trying to run this (stable-diffusion):
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uWCe41_BSRip4y4nlcB8ESQgKtr5BfrN#scrollTo=lTRtiZZk0h5d

And following a guide "for better RAM usage" replaced:
https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion.git
with:
https://github.com/chemistzombie/stable-diffusion-unfiltered.git

And am now getting following error code:

```
Cloning into 'stable-diffusion-unfiltered'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 323, done.
remote: Total 323 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 323
Receiving objects: 100% (323/323), 42.64 MiB | 37.09 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109/109), done.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
**FileNotFoundError**                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4e3cc1cf6f1b> in <module>
      2 get_ipython().system('git clone https://github.com/chemistzombie/stable-diffusion-unfiltered.git')
      3 import os
----> 4 os.chdir('stable-diffusion')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stable-diffusion'
```

I checked the link and the replacement file still exists.

I looked for any typos, checked if the linked file still exists and googled any possibly already available troubleshoot.

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. In the "Download the Repository" section, you'll need to add `-unfiltered` after stable-diffusion. For me, it threw another error when trying to view the images. Again, need to add `-unfiltered` after stable-diffusion if you get that problem.

```
# Clone the repo
!git clone https://github.com/chemistzombie/stable-diffusion-unfiltered.git
import os
os.chdir('stable-diffusion-unfiltered')
```